# create clearly distinguishable line plot of pairs of variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyr

I have the following dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

foobar <- structure(list(month = structure(c(1477872000, 1480464000, 1483142400, 
1485820800, 1488240000, 1490918400, 1493510400, 1496188800, 1498780800, 
1501459200, 1504137600, 1506729600, 1509408000, 1.512e+09, 1514678400, 
1517356800, 1519776000, 1522454400, 1525046400, 1527724800, 1530316800
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), r = c(283L, 
298L, 277L, 231L, 276L, 323L, 242L, 255L, 208L, 289L, 284L, 263L, 
280L, 278L, 269L, 288L, 255L, 324L, 339L, 355L, 300L), r_unanswered = c(133L, 
139L, 106L, 85L, 132L, 141L, 89L, 110L, 80L, 142L, 174L, 159L, 
146L, 162L, 153L, 161L, 142L, 174L, 211L, 208L, 194L), regression = c(260L, 
278L, 249L, 242L, 301L, 349L, 249L, 309L, 256L, 280L, 326L, 276L, 
299L, 322L, 235L, 281L, 256L, 293L, 356L, 307L, 279L), regression_unanswered = c(102L, 
119L, 92L, 107L, 119L, 126L, 108L, 132L, 89L, 141L, 199L, 148L, 
161L, 160L, 125L, 159L, 137L, 139L, 208L, 177L, 162L), machine_learning = c(208L, 
190L, 176L, 208L, 221L, 265L, 204L, 215L, 251L, 283L, 314L, 257L, 
250L, 290L, 240L, 290L, 275L, 295L, 292L, 316L, 324L), machine_learning_unanswered = c(64L, 
67L, 62L, 86L, 78L, 76L, 67L, 67L, 90L, 128L, 155L, 106L, 125L, 
132L, 125L, 143L, 132L, 159L, 159L, 158L, 191L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-21L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
> glimpse(foobar)
Observations: 21
Variables: 7
$ month                       <dttm> 2016-10-31, 2016-11-30, 2016-12-31, 2...
$ r                           <int> 283, 298, 277, 231, 276, 323, 242, 255...
$ r_unanswered                <int> 133, 139, 106, 85, 132, 141, 89, 110, ...
$ regression                  <int> 260, 278, 249, 242, 301, 349, 249, 309...
$ regression_unanswered       <int> 102, 119, 92, 107, 119, 126, 108, 132,...
$ machine_learning            <int> 208, 190, 176, 208, 221, 265, 204, 215...
$ machine_learning_unanswered <int> 64, 67, 62, 86, 78, 76, 67, 67, 90, 12...
```

I want to group all the non-`month` variables in pair (e.g, `r` and `r_unanswered`) and plot all of them at the same time versus the `month` column. I want to achieve three goals:

1. the pairs must be easily distinguishable, i.e, it must be easy to discern the two lines corresponding to the pair `r` and `r_unanswered`, from the two lines corresponding to `regression` and `regression_unanswered`;
2. inside each pair, it must be easy to discern by eye the `unanswered` variable from the other one.
3. the approach must scale to more pairs. In this simple example I have 3 pairs: in my real case I may have 10 or more.

I was thinking to achieve this by using the same color for each pair, and inside each pair, by plotting the `unanswered` variable as a dashed line, but I'm open to other suggestions, if you think they could be more visually appealing. Anyway, my problem is that I cannot even implement this simple idea. I tried

```
tall_unanswered <- foobar %>% select(ends_with("unanswered"), month) %>% 
  gather(key = tag, value = count, -month)
tall_total <- foobar %>% select(-ends_with("unanswered")) %>% 
  gather(key = tag, value = count, -month)
p <- ggplot(tall_total, aes(x = month, y = count, color = tag)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(data = tall_unanswered, linetype = "dashed")
```

But it doesn't work: the colors are not the same for each pair, and so I dont' manage to achieve goal 1 (each pair must be easily distinguishable from the others).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this by gathering all the columns into a long format and then creating variables based on those column names for mapping to `color` and `linetype`.  You can do this latter task with `tidyr::separate()`.

I found your particular case a little more difficult since some of the tag names contained underscores other than those directly before "unanswered".  So I first replaced `"_unanswered"` with `".unanswered"` so I could separate "tag" on a period instead of an underscore.  This makes two new columns, one for color (based on the tag name) and one for linetype (based on answered vs unanswered). The answered questions don't have info to say they are answered, so I add it with an `ifelse()` statement.

Here's the data manipulation:

```
foolong = foobar %>%
    gather(tag, count, -month) %>%
    mutate(tag = sub("_unanswered", ".unanswered", tag)) %>%
    separate(tag, into = c("name", "answered"), sep = "\\.", 
             remove = FALSE, fill = "right") %>%
    mutate(answered = ifelse(!is.na(answered), "unanswered", "answered"))
```

And then the plot can be made by mapping colors and linetypes to the new variables.

```
ggplot(foolong, aes(x = month, y = count, 
                    color = name) +
    geom_line( aes(linetype = answered))
```

[image]

You can remove or change legends as needed to suit your purpose.

**More sophisticated way to split via separate()**

As @Henrik pointed out, you can use a look-ahead via regex to split on only the underscores preceded by the word "unanswered".  This avoids my work-around `sub()` and saves a step.

That part of the code would look like:

```
foobar %>%
     gather(tag, count, -month) %>%
     separate(tag, into = c("name", "answered"), sep = "_(?=[unanswered])", 
              remove = FALSE, fill = "right")
```

Comment: To save some typing, you may use a look-ahead in `separate`: `separate(tag, into = c("name", "answered"),
           sep = "_(?=[unanswered])", fill = "right")` ...and use `replace` instead of `ifelse`: `mutate(answered = replace(answered, is.na(answered), "answered"))`. I don't think the `group` `aes` is needed: `ggplot(foolong, aes(x = month, y = count, color = name, linetype = answered)) +
  geom_line()`. Cheers

Comment: nice, but "The answered questions don't have info to say they are answered[..]" this is because they are **not** the answered questions, they are the **total** questions, i.e., answered + unanswered (you may have noticed the dataframe names: `tall_unanswered` and `tall_total`, not `tall_answered`). Anyway, I can fix that easily. Any chance you could beautify the legend a little? Maybe have it occupy less of the overall picture space, or put it **inside** the plot canvas ;-) I know it's not part of the original question, but it should be easy for an expert like you...

Comment: @Henrik what's a look-ahead? I don't understand this instruction : `separate(tag, into = c("name", "answered"), sep = "_(?=[unanswered])", fill = "right")`. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @DeltaIV Look-ahead is a regex term. Instead of me reiterating what much smarter people already have written, please search for regex tutorials, e.g. [here](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html#look-arounds)

Comment: @DeltaIV You can move the legends inside or on a different side of the plot or make them horizontal using the `theme()` elements `legend.position` and `legend.direction`, respectively.  If you run into specific problems when working with the legend I'd recommend asking a new question.

Comment: @Henrik Great!  I knew there was a logical way to split the variable that just wasn't coming to me last night.  I kept focusing on splitting on the "last" underscore and running into problems instead of thinking about using the underscore preceding "unanswered".